# Emmet Abbreviation for !important in CSS/SASS in VSCode

Tags: css, sass, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I try to avoid using `!important` in CSS as much as possible. However, when working in WordPress I have to use it occasionally to fight styles of plugins.

I use VSCode for much of this work, and in almost every way its perfect. However, if I go to use `!important`, I start by typing `!impo` - which VSCode provides an "Emmet Abbreviation" for it that suggests `!important;`

However, it's not updating my typing to `!important` - its appending `!important`. So if I type "!impo" and hit tab, the result is "impo !important;" (it also removes the initial ! which is bizarre)

Has anyone run into this issue and has a real solution? Autocomplete really helps my workflow and speed, but this particular one is a nuisance. I always have to either fully type it out or autocomplete it and delete the incorrect stuff and its very frustrating.